# add padding to ui-block-b

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I add a `padding-left` to class `ui-block-b` it has the side effect that my fixed `navbar` gets this padding as well, which I do not want. I would like only to apply the padding to the `ui-block-b` in my `ui-gid-a`. So I tried to add a new class `ui-block-b-own` but i do not get the padding in `ui-block-b`:

CSS:

```
.ui-block-b-own {
   padding-left: 10px !important
}
```

And this is the code:

```
function showDetails(index){

var suchresultat = search(); // gets either rezepte or result

$("#rezept h1").html(suchresultat[index].name);


    var inhalt = "";

var p = suchresultat[index].portionen; 
var m = suchresultat[index].menge;
var z = suchresultat[index].zubereitung;


 var textM = "";
 var textZ = "";


 for( var i = 0; i < m.length; i++ )
 {
       textM += "<br />" + m[i];
 }  

for( var i = 0; i < z.length; i++ )
 {
       textZ += "<br />" + z[i];
 }  

var por;
if (p == 1){  
por = "Portion:";
}
else {
por = "Portionen:";
}

inhalt += '<section class="ui-grid-a">';
inhalt += '<!-- Row1 -->';
inhalt += '<div class="ui-block-a"><strong>Zutaten für<br>'+ p + ' '+ por +'</strong></div>';
inhalt += '<div class="ui-block-b"><strong>Zubereitung:</strong></div>';
inhalt += '<!-- Row2 -->';
inhalt += '<div class="ui-block-a">' + textM + '</div>';
inhalt += '<div class="ui-block-b ui-block-b-own"' + textZ + '</div>';
inhalt += '</section>'; 

$("#rezeptInhalt").html(inhalt); // füllt page id rezept content

$.mobile.changePage($("#rezept"));
```

}

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: You don't need to terminate lines of HTML with `;` characters (it's mark-up, not programming). Also with the CSS you've posted we're not getting a full idea what you're doing. Could you amend this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jBR2u/) so that it's a more complete ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) representation?

Comment: Hi, the ";" was because I copied from my original code which is creating the page dynamically. See changed question. Thx, Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is generating invalid HTML.  The element in question is missing its closing `>` before you insert content via `textZ`.  CSS will therefore not be correctly applied, since the browser is probably guessing as to what the correct text content of the node should be.

```
inhalt += '<div class="ui-block-b ui-block-b-own">' + textZ + '</div>';
//----------------------------------------------^^^^
```